# How to disable tapestry t-console?

Tags: javascript, java, tapestry

Tapestry has built-in console, which shows JavaScript exceptions on page in special red boxes. Its code is located in `t5-console.js`. Is any way to disable it for specific pages (i.e. do not show this messages on page even if error occurs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "brute-force" solution is to add JS code on the page, which will erase `console` function:

```
T5.console = null;
```